# find where in boolean vector TRUE followed by FALSE

Tags: r

I have an boolean vector and need to indicate where it changes (from TRUE to FALSE).

```
input <- c(rep(TRUE,3), rep(FALSE,2), TRUE, FALSE)
input
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The result should be `c(4, 7)`. Does something for doing so already exist (in `base`)? thx, J

Comment: `which(diff(input)==-1)`

Comment: Shouldn't  the desired output be `c(4,7)`? Does `which(!input[-1] & input[-length(input)])+1` work for you?

Comment: sry, edited. it 4,7

Comment: thank you very much @HubertL - That's it!